# Export a Birt report at run time to a PDF file

Tags: javascript, pdf, birt

How do you export a birt report using javascript at runtime?

The code that I have tried is in the After Render event:

```
importPackage(Packages.org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api);

rptdoc = reportContext.getReportRunnable().getReportName();


// Open the rptDocument
  reportDocument = getReportEngine().openReportDocument(rptdoc);

  // Create the render task, configured for the wanted export format
 IRenderTask renderTask = getReportEngine().createRenderTask(reportDocument);

  IRenderOption options = new RenderOption();
  options.setOutputFormat("pdf");
  options.setOutputFileName("C:/test/myfile.pdf");
  renderTask.setRenderOption(options);

 // Launch the render task and close it 
    renderTask.render();
    renderTask.close();

    // Close the rptDocument
    reportDocument.close();
```

It runs and there are no errors but no pdf gets generated...

My requirement is to run the birt report using an URL and the report should generate itself in a folder as a pdf.

The report should only execute once. I don't want to execute the URL and then in the report it does another runAndRender in after factory, the report should export itself. Hope this makes sense.

I am using Birt 4.5.

**UPDATED CODE.**
I can get it working using the following code in the afterRender event of the report.

```
//Import Lib for birt this is standard, Import our custom birt report java lib
    importPackage(Packages.org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api);
    importPackage(Packages.company.reports.data);
    //Creates an instance of our custom class
    st = new Packages.company.reports.data.MyStandardFunctions();

//Get Global vaiables
fileDir = reportContext.getGlobalVariable("fileDir");
sTcNumber = reportContext.getGlobalVariable("sTcNumber");
sTcRevNum = reportContext.getGlobalVariable("sTcRevNum");
sTcType = reportContext.getGlobalVariable("sTcType");
sPdfPath = reportContext.getGlobalVariable("sPdfPath");
bHasErrors = reportContext.getGlobalVariable("bHasErrors");
testCertError = reportContext.getGlobalVariable("testCertError");


var re = reportContext.getReportRunnable().getReportEngine();

//Get current dreport
var pathOfReport = reportContext.getReportRunnable().getReportName().replace("file:", "");

//Create a directory for temp export reports TempExport is my dir name.
fileDir = st.createOrGetDir(fileDir);

//Only export to pdf if there were no errors.
if(bHasErrors == false)
{
    var des = re.openReportDesign(pathOfReport);     
    var ntask = re.createRunAndRenderTask(des);

    //Set parameters ie. ntask.setParameterValue("sOpiid", params["sOpiid"].value);
    ntask.setParameterValue("createPDF", false);
    ntask.setParameterValue("TCNumber", sTcNumber);
    ntask.setParameterValue("TCRevNum", sTcRevNum);
    ntask.setParameterValue("TCType", sTcType);

    //The ReportPath were you want to store the file on server(linux) test17.pdf is the name of your file. You can change this.
    var outputfile = fileDir + "temp.pdf"; //***** test17.pdf you can change to your file name.

    //This is the export options.. this will change when exporting to another format.
    var options = new PDFRenderOption();
    options.setOutputFileName(outputfile);
    options.setOutputFormat("pdf");

    ntask.setRenderOption(options);
    ntask.run();
    ntask.close();
```

The problem is that it generates the report two times when calling the report as a post call from withing a system. Now I know why it does this because it does the runandrender again. I just want it to run once and export to a pdf.

Comment: Well, the afterRender event fires *after* rendering, as its name implies. So it cannot start the rendering, of course, because it never gets fired. And your code isn't valid javascript at all, it is a mixture of Java and Javascript...

Comment: So then how do you export?

Comment: I think the question is *why* do you want to export the report using javascript at runtime? This seems a fundamental wrong usage to me.

Comment: @hvb Ok here is my scenario, We have a big system that should auto generate test certificates for material when the material is out of the plant, now what I do is I call the birt report URL(Post call) with its parameters form RPG code, to generate the report on a windows server on a network. From there the pdf will be used by other systems. Hopes this explained what I am trying to achieve? So its a post call to the url to generate it we dont want the pdf to open in a web browser.

Comment: I can create a wrapper java web service to call the report or generate the report but this feels to me like I am creating a program to call the report instead of just calling a post URL that will generate the report...

Comment: Please see updated code as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Java wrapper service is what I would recommend. You can use the RunAndRenderTask then instead of separate RunTask and RenderTask.

Or you can use the Web Viewer Servlet and retrieve the PDF output as the HTTP response.

Anyway, it is the wrong approach if you try to call any of these tasks from Javascript inside the report itself.

See https://wiki.eclipse.org/Integration_Examples_(BIRT) for an examples of the Java API and https://www.eclipse.org/birt/documentation/integrating/viewer-usage.php for the viewer (you'll want to use /run in your URL).